# JQuery ajax fails on POST to express.js server

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express

**The main problem seems to be** that jQuery is sending the following header in the AJAX request:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/enter HTTP/1.1
```

, while it should be

```
POST /enter HTTP/1.1
```

**In more detail, this is how my server and client are set up and the exact requests and responses:**

I have a pretty simple setup with `express.js` on the server and `jQuery` on the client.  All I need is a POST request to the server.

This is, more or less, what the server looks like:

```
app.post('/enter', function(req, res){
 console.log(req.body)
 res.json({flag: true})
})
```

Here's what the jQuery looks like:

```
$.ajax(
 { url: '/enter'
 , type: 'POST'
 , cache: false
 , data:
    { field1: 1, field2: 2 }
 , success: function(data){
    alert('Success!')
   }
 , error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err){
    alert('text status '+textStatus+', err '+err)
   }
})
```

Surely enough, the server's `console.log` confirms the correct data.  The alert message I get after the AJAX is simply `text status error err`.

Chrome tells me the request headers are:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/enter HTTP/1.1
Origin: http://localhost:3000
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/11.10 Chromium/15.0.874.106 Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:3000/?
```

The response to that request is:

```
HTTP/1.1 0 undefined
```

I also used telnet to gain some clarity into the situation.  In telnet, I see the response is:

```
404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: text/plain
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

28
Cannot POST /http://localhost:3000/enter
0
```

So the problem seems to be the line `POST http://localhost:3000/enter HTTP/1.1`.  If I send the headers with that line changed to `POST /enter HTTP/1.1`, it works perfectly!

I'm using Chrome 15 on Ubuntu 11.  I've also tried it with Firefox 9.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try `res.json({flag: true}, 200);` instead? It looks like for some reason the status code isn't defaulting to 200.

Comment: I tried that, but I got the same result :/.  It seems to be how jQuery or the XHR is requesting the page that's problematic.

Comment: is jquery script running on the same domain and port?

Comment: Are you calling any other methods on the `res` object or passing it to any other library? Something must be setting the statusCode to `undefined` somewhere.

Comment: No, that is the only code touching the `res` object.  I know that the server works fine because with Telnet it works properly, so it must be the way jQuery or the XHR calls it that's the problem (since it request `POST http://localhost:3000/enter` instead of `POST /enter`).

Comment: Also, it is the same domain and port.  In this case, `localhost:3000`.

Answer (score 3):

It seemed to have to do with how the form was being submitted, strangely.

I misunderstood the semantics of the `<button>` tag, and tried to use it in my form like so:

```
<form>
 <button id="enter">Enter</button>
</form>
```

I created the event handler like this:

```
$('#enter').click(function(){ /* AJAX stuff... */ })
```

When I changed the HTML to

```
<form>
 <input type="button" id="enter" value="Enter">
</form>
```

, it worked properly.

However, it's not entirely clear to me why it created the errors.  It seems to have something to do with the fact that the button submitted the form.  If someone could explain this to me, I'd appreciate it.

Either way, thank you for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the type attribute in your button element so it behaves like a button input type, like so:

```
<button id="enter" type="button">Enter</button>
```

The default button type for most browsers is "submit". This is not guaranteed, though, so it is always a good idea to specify a type.